# How to fix 'error: Error: syntax error - at value'

Tags: node.js, database, couchbase, sql++

I have objects like:

```
address: {
  "phone" : 888,
  "value" : 12
}
```

And in `WHERE` i need to find objects by address.value, but in SQL there's function `value()`, so i always get an error.

I do it from node.js. Are there any variants to solve this without changing objects?
Sql request like:

```
SELECT count(*) as size FROM addresses WHERE address.value = 12
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VALUE is a reserved word. If you want to use it as a common identifier, you need to enclose it in backticks:

```
SELECT count(*) as size FROM addresses WHERE address.`value` = 12
```

Comment: Thank you so much!